# Delete child table records from database using EF Core 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I have a solution where I am using the repository pattern along with UnitOfWork.

I have a repository for aggregate root (`ParentTable`) which has a relation with `ChildOne`, `ChildTwo` tables.

```
ParentTable? parentTable = await _unitOfWork.ParentRepository.GetSingleAsync(ParentId);

if (parentTable == null)
    return false;

List<ChildTwo> childrenToDelete = new()
            { 
                new ChildTwo { ChildTwoId = 3, ParentId = parentTable.ParentId }, 
                new ChildTwo { ChildTwoId = 4, ParentId = parentTable.ParentId }
            };
parentTable.Name = "Parent Name Updated";

foreach (var T in childrenToDelete)
    parentTable.ChildTwo.Remove(T);

await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

In this code, after calling `SaveChangesAsync()`, it is updating `ParentTable` rows, but not deleting `ChildTwo` rows added to navigation `ICollection` property.

I've looked various solutions available online but nothing seems to be working, in EF Core 7 there is no `Attach()` method to mark it deleted.

Comment: You did not load child record from database that's why they are not being tracked, one solution is to to also load child record when you are loading parent, and other could be attach child table to parent set state to modified.

Comment: @sairfan how do you attach child table to parent, I don't want to load Child records at the time of Getting Parent

Comment: Right now I do not have code with me but it should be like this `context.Category.Attach(entity)` and if you try be setting state should be like `context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted` if it does not work please google on these keywords, EF attaching child entity,  please note that these example are for EF, not sure if you are looking for core version.

Comment: @sairfan it will not work as I don't have direct access to dbContext, I am using UnitOfWork and If I try to attach parentTable.ChildTwo.Attach() this also won't work.

Answer (score 1):

One more reason not to use Generic Repository patterns... :)

One option to check for, or enhance your repository method is the option to retrieve related entities with the parent. For instance:

```
Task<T?> async GetSingleAsync<T>(int id, params string[] includes)
{
    var query = _context.Set<T>()
        .WHere(x => x.Id == id);
    foreach(var include in includes)
        query = query.Include(include);

    return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Alternatively this could be done with a `params` of Expressions, but either way has limitations on how to handle reference depth like supporting `Include` and `ThenInclude` for instance. With a method like the above available you could use:

```
ParentTable? parentTable = await _unitOfWork.ParentRepository.GetSingleAsync(ParentId, "ChildTwo");
if (parentTable == null)
    return false;
 
 foreach(var childId in childIdsToRemove)
 {
     var child = parentTable.ChildTwo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == childId);
     if (child != null)
         parentTable.ChildTwo.Remove(child);
 }
 
  _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

When modifying an entity's related children, you essentially want to either eager load the collection or explicitly load the collection. As a quick hack you can Attach a stub and remove items that way but I do not recommend using that approach for child entities as you will always need to check if the DbContext happens to be tracking a reference for each item before attaching it otherwise you will get an seemingly intermittent/situational exception when it encounters that scenario.

This is a good example of why I don't recommend using a Generic or per-Entity Repository pattern with EF. If the code had just used an injected `DbContext`, or a repository pattern that exposed `IQueryable`, the solution would be as simple as adding the `.Include(x => x.ChildTwos)` or with EF Core you could even Just load the items to delete using:

```
var childrenToDelete = await _context.Entry(parent)
   .Collection(x => x.ChildTwo)
   .Query()
   .Where(c => childIdsToDelete.Contains(c.Id))
   .ToListAsync();

foreach(var child in childrenToDelete)
    parent.ChildTwo.Remove(child);
```

That explicitly loads only the child entities from the parent that were found in the ID list rather than eager loading a Cartesian Product of all children like `Include()` would do.

Comment: You are right, looks like Generic Repository Pattern does have many issues regarding Child Entities

Comment: It's only the tip of the iceberg. Resolving eager loading, handling projection, pagination, custom sorting and filtering rules.... It's a pretty big list where the repository either severely handcuff's your options, or needs to essentially try and rewrite the capabilities that EF already does, which in the end *still* need to conform to the rules and EF-isms that people try to abstract away with Repositories.  Some people assume they will have a problem and think "Abstracting with Generic Repositories could avoid  this!". Now they have a dozen problems. :)